# Que significa @aspect en spring

Tags: spring-boot

por ejemplo revisando este codigo

```
@Aspect
class CommandExecuteInterceptor implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;
```

que significa @aspect, para que usarlo, cuando usarlo?

Comment: Si entiendes inglés: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto tiene que ver con el paradigma  de la programación Orientada a Aspectos(AOP), te comento brevemente:

La programación orientada a aspectos (AOP - Aspect Oriented Programming) es un paradigma de programación que intenta formalizar y representar de forma concisa los elementos que son transversales a todo el sistema, ¿Cómo es esto? un ejemplo común es el de control de permisos de ejecución de ciertos métodos en una clase.

```
public class ObjetoDeNegocio {
   public void metodoDeNegocio1() throws SinPermisoException {
        validarPermisos();
        //resto del código
        ...
   }

   public void metodoDeNegocio2() throws SinPermisoException {
        validaPermisos();
        //resto del código
        ...
   }     
}
```

En AOP, a los elementos que son transversales a la estructura del sistema y se pueden modularizar gracias a las construcciones que aporta el paradigma se les denomina aspectos (aspects).

Un aspecto (aspect) es un conjunto de advices. Siguiendo la sintaxis de AspectJ, los aspectos se representan como clases Java, marcadas con la anotación @Aspect. En Spring, además, un aspecto debe ser un bean, por lo que se tiene que anotarlo como tal

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;



@Component
@Aspect
public class EjemploDeAspecto {

  //aquí vendrían los advices...
}
```

[Mayor info: Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)